# How to access Evernote API in Firefox/Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, evernote

I am willing to fiddle with Evernote API and use it Chrome/FF extensions. What I learnt that so far no JS API available which makes me to think to make a middle tier service in php/python and let my extension to access Evernote via that service.

The place where I am confused is authentication. How do I make a user to authenticate with Evernote from a browser extension? If it;s showing a html static page which then redirects to EverNote Login Page and store access token etc at server side. How will my extension remember logged In details and make calls to service and create/retrieve notes in my Chrome extension.

The workflow of App is following:

- User will be able to login on Evernote via Extension(by accessing page of Logging).
- After successful logging notes will be retrieved via middle tier service in Chrome Extension via Ajax Request.
- USer can then post note via AJAX call to service which will then eventually store in Evernote via its API

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no official javascript API. But you can find a few un-official ones.
Take a look here for example : http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/22476-api-for-javascript/
Don't know how they work however.

Here's another solution :
Not sure it's the right way to do it but you could mimic the way the evernote webclipper works.
Basically it uses a internal customerKey / customerSecret along with the username and password to retrieve an oauthToken. Then it uses this OauthToken for all api calls.

You can find the process in the Auth.js file of the webclipper source code.
On a mac, the file is located in /Users/%user%/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/5.9.5_0/js/main/Auth.js

I don't know on other systems but it shoudn't be too difficult to find on Google.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can find an official JavaScript library. (I'm not sure limitations of Chrome extension though)

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js

I find it here.
http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/34619-how-to-access-evernote-api-in-firefoxchrome-extensions/#entry250743

The FAQ of the library says that

```
Can I test my code in the browser

Yes. You can test your code in Chrome. Open Chrome using open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security .
```

Comment: This is a great official quick start guide: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/javascript.php